# BackAndroid 'hardwareBackPress' event is not working

Tags: android, react-native

According to react-native docs [BackAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backandroid.html#content) component with simple callback should not allow exit the app on back button press, but it looks like the event listener isn't called at all.

```
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
  return true;
});
```

What should be changed to allow event listener triggering?

Comment: what did you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3223), [Satyajit Sahoo](https://github.com/satya164) provided a workable solution:

add the following to MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe Yevgen is asking how to do this in React Native.  You have described the Android native onBackPressed in Java

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this.goBack(); before you return true.

```
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() { 
    this.goBack(); 
    return true; 
});
```